# Forced password change after x days stuck in a loop

Tags: php

I am implementing a forced password change after 90 days for a web application - at the top of an application header file which is called on every page I check the age of the password and if it is over 90 days force the user to a password change page. This all works fine.

The problem is the password change page also calls the header page which does the check so it gets the same look and feel as the rest of the site but, of course, it then sticks in a never ending loop of check and redirect - what is the best way to prevent this? I don't want to have to have the password change page with no formatting, nor as a pop up and I ideally don't want to use a different template header without the password check as I will forget to update the second one when I make changes.

How else can I approach this? I want to make sure that the user cannot do anything other than change their password once they pass the 90 day mark.

Thanks
Jason

Comment: Please remember that forced password changes are a bad idea. People tend to use worse passwords since they have to remember a new one ever few months.

Comment: I hadn't considered this - we do check password quality so, simplistically, an 8 character all lower case letters only password won't be accepted as it is not strong enough so they have to either make passwords much longer or mix in different case, numbers or punctuation. It is also worth pointing out that the application contains sensititve information so users expect security.

Answer (score 2):

Simply modify the check so it does not redirect if the password-change page was loaded.

A clean approach would be (assuming you don't do OOP and don't use one of the PHP frameworks) to `define('ALLOW_EXPIRED_PASSWORD', 1);` before including the file and in the function that performs the redirect check for `defined('ALLOW_EXPIRED_PASSWORD')` and only redirect if that check returned false.

Answer (score 0):

Something I would do in your situation (sounds like it's plain ole php) which sounds easier in your case is a simple if statement, which checks for the filename the user is accessing.

In this way, you wouldn't have to explicitly set the constant ThiefMaster is mentioning.